# Horizontal scrolling doesn't work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-website

I am making a website which has two pages next to each other. The other page stays hidden with 0 width when the front page is in the view. A button is used to activate the other page, scroll right to only have it in the view, and then disabling the first page setting it's width to 0 for the time being. The same process is used to return to the first page.

The problem introduced itself when I was creating responsivity to mobile screen sizes. When inspecting in chrome using the "phone mode" it activates the second page, but refuses to scroll there using the script, but enabling mobile scrolling manually. Scrolling vertically to the top of the page works fine.

Here is a simplified example of the problem you can try.

```js
function ScrollUpAndActivateCertificates() {
  // Check if page is at the top
  if (window.scrollY === 0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("certificates")[0].classList.remove("pageClosed");
    document.getElementsByClassName("certificates")[0].classList.add("certOpenLeft");
    scrollRightAndRemoveFrontpage();
  }

  // Scroll to top and restart function
  else {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
    setTimeout(ScrollUpAndActivateCertificates, 1000);
  }
}

function scrollRightAndRemoveFrontpage() {

  window.scrollTo({
    left: window.innerWidth,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });

  if (window.scrollX >= window.innerWidth - 100) // Needs leeway for windows scrollbar?
  {
    // Disable front page
    document.getElementsByClassName("frontpage")[0].classList.remove("pageOpen");
    document.getElementsByClassName("frontpage")[0].classList.add("pageClosed");
    // Set cert as the only page
    document.getElementsByClassName("certificates")[0].classList.add("certMoveToFront");
    document.getElementsByClassName("certificates")[0].classList.remove("certOpenLeft");
  } else {
    setTimeout(scrollRightAndRemoveFrontpage, 1000);
  }

}

function ScrollUpAndActivateFrontpage() {
  if (window.scrollY === 0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("frontpage")[0].classList.remove("pageClosed");
    document.getElementsByClassName("frontpage")[0].classList.add("pageOpen");

    document.getElementsByClassName("certificates")[0].classList.remove("certMoveToFront");
    document.getElementsByClassName("certificates")[0].classList.add("certOpenLeft");

    // Disabling active styles
    document.getElementsByClassName("certificates")[0].classList.remove("certMoveToFront");

    // Making sure the page is scrolled to the right when other page is activated
    window.scrollTo({
      left: window.innerWidth,
      behavior: "auto"
    });

    ScrollLeftAndRemoveCertificates();

  } else {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
    setTimeout(ScrollUpAndActivateFrontpage, 1000);
  }
}

function ScrollLeftAndRemoveCertificates() {
  window.scrollTo({
    left: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });

  if (pageXOffset == 0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("certificates")[0].classList.add("pageClosed");
    document.getElementsByClassName("certificates")[0].classList.remove("certOpenLeft");
  } else {
    setTimeout(ScrollLeftAndRemoveCertificates, 1000);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/* Styles for moving the pages */

#horizontalPagesWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.pageOpen {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.pageClosed {
  max-width: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.certOpenLeft {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 100%;
}

.certMoveToFront {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.certMoveToSide {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  left: 100%;
}


/* Page styles*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .contentContainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .contentContainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="horizontalPagesWrapper">
    <div class="frontpage pageOpen">
      <div class="contentContainer">
        <h1>HTML Scrolling example</h1>
        <button class="infoButton" onclick="ScrollUpAndActivateCertificates()">SIDE PAGE</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="certificates pageClosed">
      <div class="contentContainer">
        <h1>Welcome to the side page</h1>
        <button class="infoButton" onclick="ScrollUpAndActivateFrontpage()">FRONT PAGE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Changing pages works when using a desktop browser. I expected it to work as it does on a normal browser on a computer, but it stops working as soon as you introduce mobile screens with touch functionality. The screen does activate and you can scroll with your thumb, which is not intentional. The front page does not deactivate when scrolled to all the way right and scripted horizontal scrolling won't happen.

I noticed that changing the width in the class `.certOpenLeft` to absurd numbers like `10000px` instead of `100%` enables the scrolling, but it otherwise breaks the intended look of the website.

Comment: Hi mico vihavainen,
I tried replicating the issue you mentioned on my phone, but was unable to do so. Could you please provide more information regarding the device you are using, such as whether it is an iOS or Android device, and the browser you were using at the time of the issue? This will help me better understand the problem.

Comment: Hi @Ali_Sdg90. I am using chrome's inspect tool's "device mode" on a windows desktop and an android phone with chrome. For me this problem is persistent on both.